# Export a web page as a pdf

Tags: pdf, web, printing

I want to print a web page in a pdf or extract it as a html single file.

I use data analytics tool (Apache Zeppelin) where I create a report. I want to create a static report from this tool for demo purposes. I cannot export this report from the tool (it is not embedded as an option yet) so I want to try to print in pdf. If I try to simply print it in pdf the result is a mess (images overleaping with text).

Has anyone has an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Someone suggested a solution [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1774) that you could try. Let me know if it works. Here is the code too:

```
%angular

<div id="divtest">Wooooo!</div>
<button id="cmd" type="submit" onclick="useJSPDF()">Generate PDF</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function useJSPDF() {
var element = $('#divtest');
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.fromHTML(element.html(), 15, 15,

{ 'width': 170, }
);
doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
}

if (window.jsPDF) {
} else

{ var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript'; sc.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js'; sc.onerror = function(err) \{ alert(err); }
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sc);
}

</script>
```

Once the code is being executed, a button should be displayed like this
[image]

Comment: Did not work for me. ```(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: useJSPDF is not defined```

Comment: My answer has been updated. Does it generate a button like mine?

Comment: Still did not work for me. I end up using the Export as Image from the Firefox and the SingleFile Extension in the Google Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle?hl=en